# File Download Unable to Reach Controller Throwing 405 Error

Tags: asp.net-core, file-upload

I'm trying to call a file download routine from my page, but it throws a 405 error before it even hits the action in the controller. Here is the way I am calling the routine:

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("DownloadFile", new { controller="Attachment" , attachmentId=Model.IssueData.AttachmentList[i].attachmentId })" class="fa fa-download "></a>
```

It seems to generate the correct string:
https://localhost:44339/Attachment/DownloadFile?attachmentId=4

However it never reaches the DownloadFile action of the Attachment controller:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[HttpPost]
public FileResult DownloadFile(int attachmentId)
{
    AttachmentModel file = _adoSqlService.DownloadFile(attachmentId);
    return File(file.aFileData, file.aFileType, file.aFileName);
}
```

Instead of hitting the controller the page throws a 405 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one in your `a` tag is an `HttpGet` request, but you are using `[HttpPost]` in the background, which will cause the method not allowed.

You can modify your Action as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
public FileResult DownloadFile(int attachmentId)
{
    AttachmentModel file = _adoSqlService.DownloadFile(attachmentId);
    return File(file.aFileData, file.aFileType, file.aFileName);
}
```